# How to construct a wxListBox with option of adding entries, without knowing the number in advance?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, listbox, wxwidgets

I have have a wxListBox, which is constructed like this :

```
wxString choices[8] =  {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };

m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox( panelOne, ListBoxOneID,wxPoint(40,250), wxSize(260,125), 8, choices, wxLB_SINGLE|wxLB_HSCROLL, wxDefaultValidator );
```

This kind of initialization makes room for 8 pre-defined entries in the list. But adding any extra ones ( 9th... ) results in a crash.

How should I correct this code, if I want the list to be initialized with these 8 pre-defined entries, but with possibility of adding 9th, 10th... So as many as the program will require, not predetermined ?

**EDIT :** Some extra code to hopefully help find the problem

```
static unsigned int k = 0 ;
m_listboxSorted->SetString(k, "some text");
k++;
```

This code is part of the handler function which ( on button clicked ) does some processing and also adds an entry to the list box. And apart from the constructor :

```
wxListBox *m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox;
```

That is all the code that I see has anything to do with the list box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `SetString()` to add a string to the listbox, it can only be used to modify an existing string (just think about it: what would `SetString(10, "whatever")` do for an empty listbox, what would be shown in the first 10 items before the string `"whatever"` in the 11th line?).

You should use `Append()` instead. This also will free you from the need to track the index manually (of course, you could always just get it from the listbox itself using its `GetCount()`).

Answer (score 1):

If using C++ 11,the following should work:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<wxString> choices = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
```

Then when you want to add a string:

```
choices.push_back("8");
```

If you're not using C++ 11:

```
#include <vector>
//...
wxString choices_vals[8] =  {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
std::vector<wxString> choices(choices_vals, choices_vals + 8);
```

The same `push_back` call would be used to add an element at runtime.

If you want to start out with an empty vector, then just declare it and add the entries when you see fit:

```
std::vector<wxString> choices; // vector is empty
//...
choices.push_back("0");  // add an item
```

Now in your function call, it would look like this:

```
m_listboxSorted = new wxListBox( panelOne, ListBoxOneID,wxPoint(40,250), 
                                 wxSize(260,125), choices.size(), &choices[0],
                                 wxLB_SINGLE|wxLB_HSCROLL,  wxDefaultValidator )
```

Note the use of the `size()` member function for `std::vector`, as well as passing the address of the first element of the vector.

Edit:

With wxWidgets, you have the `wxArrayString` class, described here:  http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_array_string.html

Although I believe the `std::vector` would also work, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't use C++11 so I tried the 2nd variant. However the results weren't as desired. List was initialized with numbers from 0-7. Then on every time button for adding items is clicked, it starts adding from top, going down, and replacing original entries (numbers) with new ones. Apart from that, it works only until 9th entry is added, after that it crashes again. Apologies if I didn't form my question properly.

Comment: @JamesC - Sorry, I don't use wxWidgets.  But as a guess, maybe you need to recreate the control with the new number of buttons?  Whatever the case, what I posted as an answer is if you want to dynamically change the `choices` array -- it has little to do with what wxWidgets function to call to properly redisplay buttons.

Comment: Ah alright I see now. But the problem remains that "choices_vals" still has to be presented. I suppose it can be worked around, even if you don't know how many new entries there will be while the program is running. But it wouldn't look nice and elegant, at least not from what I can do =)

Comment: @JamesC Well, the vector can be empty, and you add the entries one by one using `push_back` whenever you want/need to add an entry.  See my edits to the answer

Comment: Would you care to explain, what causes this build error : `std::vector<wxString>' has no member named 'pushback'` , please ?

Comment: @JamesC - The member function is `push_back`, not `pushback`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: How careless of me, thank you =) I'm still struggling with making it work as I want though. But I guess I can hit it on the right way from here.